# In Windows 10, is there a command similar to wuapp.exe that will launch the Windows Update GUI?

Tags: command-line, windows-update, windows-10

In previous versions of windows running the command `wuapp.exe` would launch the Windows Update GUI.

I want to be able to launch the Windows Update GUI from within a script/program thus would like to know if there is a replacement or similar command that works on Windows 10?

Answer (score 25):

What you're looking for is `ms-settings:windowsupdate`

From the run dialog this will open the Windows Update settings page. From cmd you need to add `start` infront of the string (there may be a better way, but I haven't spent much time looking.)

There is a list of all of these strings on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Dn741261.aspx).

Comment: THANK YOU. I have this "Critical Error" happening in Windows 10 that doesn't let me access the Start Menu or anything Metro related. This helped me at least open Windows Update to see if a patch could be found to fix the error. I'll let you know how that goes anyway .. but for now, thank you! :)

Comment: Does **cortana**h need to be running for **ms-settings** to be recognized as a command? I broke mine and it won't fire from **run** (Win+R), **cmd.exe** or **powershell**.

Comment: I see, ms-settings alone isn't recognized. ms-settings:about works.

Answer (score 4):

The old Desktop Windows Update UI is removed in Windows 10 . Run `ms-settings:windowsupdate` to open the Windows Update view from the settings app.